# What's the best way to get a Class object for an array type?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, constants, literals

It's easy to get a class literal for a class:

```
String.class
```

But how can I get a class object for an array type?

This works, but it's ugly, and probably not a compile time constant:

```
new byte[0].getClass()
```

I looked in the JLS but the only thing I found out is that what I'm calling a "class literal" isn't a "literal" according to the JLS definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use a class literal, even for an array type.  This compiles just fine.

```
Class<String[]> clazz = String[].class;
Class<byte[]> clazz2 = byte[].class;
```

[Section 15.8.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) states:

> A *class literal* is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, **array**, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type `void`, followed by a '.' and the token `class`.

(bold emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply type

```
Class<?> clazz = byte[].class;
```